# Insert Into Oracle XMLTYPE column with ExecuteStoreCommand()

Tags: .net, oracle, insert

I have a table like

```
Id (int) | xml (xmltype)
```

I want to insert to this table as:

```
string Sql = "insert into MyTable (xml) values (xmltype(:0))";
myxml = "<root>very long xml...</root>";
MyEntity.ExecuteStoreCommand(Sql, myxml);
```

If the xml is very long (more than 4000 chars) this returns the following error:

> ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

I have searched the internet, and found that "myxml" should be "clob" but entity framework sends it as "long".

How can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching and working and trying, I have came up with the following solution:

You cannot use ExecuteStoreCommand() method in order to insert a string which is longer than 4K.

In order to add string more than 4K, you have to bind parameters.

In order to bind parameters in .net, we will utilize odp.net.

**Step One**

Add the reference to your project.

1. Right click references on .net project explorer window and click add reference.
2. On .net tab, find Oracle.DataAccess and add this to project.

**Step Two**

Add this to your top of your page:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
```

**Step Three**

Now we code:

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Here comes your oracle connection string."))
{
    con.Open();

    //prepare the command
    OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (:param0) ";

    //define the parameter.
    OracleParameter param0 = new OracleParameter();
    param0.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob;
    param0.Value = "very long xml...";
    param0.ParameterName = "param0";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param0);

    try
    {
        AffectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //execute the query
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now it should work like a charm :)

**Notes**

1- Do not use System.Data.OracleClient, it is deprecated.

2- If your table column data type is xmltype and still get an error, change your datatype to clob.

Hope this helps others...